# Elasticsearch Deleting all nested object with a specific datetime

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-painless

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.6 and I have a `schedule` nested field with nested objects that look like this

```
{
              "status": "open",
              "starts_at": "2020-10-13T17:00:00-05:00",
              "ends_at": "2020-10-13T18:00:00-05:00"
            },
            {
              "status": "open",
              "starts_at": "2020-10-13T18:00:00-05:00",
              "ends_at": "2020-10-13T19:30:00-05:00"
            }
```

what I'm looking for is a `Painless` query that will delete multiple nested objects that is equals to the `starts_at` field. I've tried multiple ways but none worked, they run correctly but don't delete the targeted objects

Comment: Share your current query -- maybe we can fine tune it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to do this with looping over it and using `SimpleDateFormat`

```
POST index/_update_by_query
    {
    "script": {"source": "for(int i=0;i< ctx._source.schedule.length;i++){ 
                               SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss'); 
                               boolean equalDateTime = sdformat.parse(ctx._source.schedule[i].starts_at).compareTo(sdformat.parse(params.starts_at)) == 0; 
                               if(equalDateTime) {
                                ctx._source.schedule.remove(i)
                               }
                           }",
                           "params": {
                                      "starts_at": "2020-10-13T17:00:00-05:00"
                                     },
                           "lang": "painless"
    },
      "query":{
        "bool": {"must":[
          {"terms":{"_id":["12345"]}}
         ]}}
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [UpdateByQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) for the same.

```
POST <indexName>/<type>/_update_by_query
{
  "query":{ // <======== Filter out the parent documents containing the specified nested date
    "match": {
      "schedule.starts_at": "2020-10-13T17:00:00-05:00"
    }
  },
  "script":{ // <============ use the script to remove the schedule containing specific start date
    "inline": "ctx._source.schedule.removeIf(e -> e.starts_at == '2020-10-13T17:00:00-05:00')"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not gonna work since it is a date field comparision won't work with `==`